# How to add more options without indentation error?

Tags: python

Hello I am editing this code since I want to add a sub menu and a function in each selected option but whenever I add even a print it gives me an error and it is annoying I have tried in every way but the error is constant and annoying

```
import os

 

def menu():

    """

    Función que limpia la pantalla y muestra nuevamente el menu

    """

    os.system('clear') # NOTA para windows tienes que cambiar clear por cls

    print ("Selecciona una opción")

    print ("\t1 - primera opción")

    print ("\t2 - segunda opción")

    print ("\t3 - tercera opción")

    print ("\t9 - salir")

 

 

while True:

    # Mostramos el menu

    menu()

 

    # solicituamos una opción al usuario

    opcionMenu = input("inserta un numero valor >> ")

 

    if opcionMenu=="1":

        print ("")

        input("Has pulsado la opción 1...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")

    elif opcionMenu=="2":

        print ("")

        input("Has pulsado la opción 2...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")

    elif opcionMenu=="3":

        print ("")

        input("Has pulsado la opción 3...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")

    elif opcionMenu=="9":

        break

    else:

        print ("")

        input("No has pulsado ninguna opción correcta...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")
```

for example in the first if
I want to add a sub menu like this

```
if opcionMenu=="1":

        print ("Selecciona una opción")

        print ("\t1 - primera opción")

        print ("\t2 - segunda opción")

        print ("\t3 - tercera opción")

        print ("\t9 - salir")
        n=input("Has pulsado la opción 1...\npulsa una tecla para continuar")
  
        print(function(n))
```

if I wanted to do this inside it is useless is possible or some idea

Comment: Can you post the full traceback/content of the error you're receiving? It will help us narrow down the problem.

Comment: Have you made sure that you're using spaces (or tabs) throughout the file and not a mix of both?

Comment: @JoshHonig  unindent does not match any outer indentation level